# jquery function scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm not understanding function scope here.  I have a button when clicked shows a dialog with a textarea.  Inside that textarea I populate it with a url that someone can then copy for their camera setup.

```
<button id="axis-details" onclick="apikey('<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>');">API Key</button>

function apikey(camerahash)
{
   var $key = "http://myhost.com/notify.php/" +camerahash;
   return $key;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
$dialog.append('Please copy this key for camera setup: ')
       .append('<p><textarea id=\"textbox\">'+apikey(camerahash)+'</textarea></p>') //ERROR here that camerahash is not defined
       .append('<p>For more information see: <a href=\"http://www.myhost.com/forum/2-quickstart-docs\">setup</a></p>');
$dialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'API Key'
});

$('#axis-details').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $dialog.dialog('open');
});
});
```

Function apikey(camerahash) does return the value I expect.  I get an error indicated above that camerahash is not defined.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your code you never initialize `camerahash` did you forget something?

Comment: the error indicating that camerahash is not defined is because camerahash is not defined... not sure how much clearer that can get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you actually want:

```
<button id="axis-details">API Key</button>

function apikey(camerahash)
{
   var $key = "http://myhost.com/notify.php/" +camerahash;
   return $key;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
$dialog.append('Please copy this key for camera setup: ')
       .append('<p><textarea id=\"textbox\">'+apikey(<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>)+'</textarea></p>') //ERROR here that camerahash is not defined
       .append('<p>For more information see: <a href=\"http://www.myhost.com/forum/2-quickstart-docs\">setup</a></p>');
$dialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'API Key'
});

$('#axis-details').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $dialog.dialog('open');
});
});
```

Comment: I wish it was that simple.  The php code goes through a loop to print out the camera_hash.  Thanks for the help, I guess I've got a bigger problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is only defined in your apikey function, you need to also pass it in from your jquery method,

```
 .append('<p><textarea id=\"textbox\">'+apikey('<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>')+'</textarea></p>')
```

Or even easier, modify your function to  not need the input,

```
function apikey()
{
   var $key = "http://myhost.com/notify.php/" +'<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>';
   return $key;
}
```

Comment: Or even easier still, don't use a function!